# SQL Server logging within Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm looking at an xel file that's been exported from Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.

One specific query:

```
select top 1 dist.Distance...
```

which should only "affect" one row. Without `top 1`, the query would never return more than 10 rows.

But the xel file reads that the affected_rows were 210720 for that query.

What does that number represent?

EDIT - Adding full query

```
declare @Latitude float = 0,@Longitude float = 0

select top 1 dist.Distance, f.id, f.SEOPageTitle, f.SEOMetroCity, f.SEOCity1, f.SEOCity2, f.SEOCity3, f.MetaDescription, f.MetaKeywords 
FROM f (NOLOCK) 
join (select distinct f.id, min(dbo.CalculateDistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, z.Latitude, z.Longitude)) 'Distance' 
        FROM f2 (NOLOCK) 
        join FZipCode fz (NOLOCK) on f2.id = fz.FID 
        join (select distinct ZipCode, Latitude, Longitude from ZipCodes (NOLOCK)) z on z.ZIPCode = fz.ZIPCode 
        where f.Activated = 1 and dbo.CalculateDistance(@Latitude, @Longitude, z.Latitude, z.Longitude) <= 30 
        group by f2.id) dist on f.id = dist.FID 
order by Distance
```

Comment: Your query normally returned 210720 rows (affected), but your TOP 1 only kept the first one. Should be the only possible explanation.

Comment: @ThomasG - that query never returns more than 10 rows max

Comment: Can you show us the full query?

Comment: @LeonYue Added full query

Comment: @duckmike try to change top 1 to top 10. How many rows return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the xel file reads that the affected_rows were 210720 for that
>   query. What does that number represent?

*.xel files are DB Audit files.

A recent version of SQL Server has new columns in [sys.fn_get_audit_file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):.

```
Column name     | Type   | Description
--------------- |--------|------------------------------
response_rows   | bigint | Applies to: Azure SQL DB only    
affected_rows   | bigint | Applies to: Azure SQL DB only
```

Unfortunately, these columns are not documented at all.

However, I have a few assumptions:

- I think your question refers to a value of column `affected_rows` of that function.
- I assume that another column -  `response_rows` returns a right value = 1. It shows the number of columns in a dataset that was sent to a client app.
- I assume that `affected_rows` returns the number of changed rows **internally**. Perhaps it is about tempdb *work tables*, but it does not show the number of rows that are sent to the client.

**Update 2019-02-26:**

@duckmike confirmed assumptions. `response_rows` has value 1 which represents the number of rows in a dataset that was sent by azure db to a client. The column `affected_rows` perhaps has some different meaning for SELECT statements.

Comment: Right.. that lack of documentation makes this question unanswerable.

Comment: Yeps, true, wondering can you see in that xel file a column  `response_rows` for your query? If so, what is the value?

Comment: @duckmike, column names are also logical. response_rows = the number of rows in a dataset sent to the client. affected_rows  = the number of rows that been affected by query. Since the query is SELECT (not update, insert, delete) I think that column shows the number of rows involved by internal objects to make query result produced. IMHO, your question is answered :)